# System CPU Time and User CPU Time Calculation for a Process in Linux

Tags: linux, process, cpu, time

I want to calculate CPU time consumption of a particular process in system mode and user mode using statistics present in `/proc/<PID>`.

There are two fields utime and stime in `/proc/<PID>/stat` file, whose documentation says:

- utime: Amount of time that this process has been scheduled in user mode
- stime: Amount of time that this process has been scheduled in kernel(system) mode

I'm calculating CPU time consumption(in seconds) in system mode using following formula: (stime / No of clock ticks). For CPU time consumption in user mode I'm using the formula: (utime/ No of clock ticks)

I validated output of `atop` command for system and user CPU time but my calculation is coming out wrong.

**NOTE:** Please let me know if I'm evaluating wrong fields for system and user CPU time for a process? Or what is the right way to calculate?

P.S I'm dividing these fields by No of Clock ticks in a second in order to calculate system CPU time and User CPU time in seconds as utime and stime are expressed in terms of CPU clock ticks.

Comment: How do you determine the number of clock ticks?

Comment: using sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK) function

Comment: I think that's correct. You can make `ps` print the multiplier that it uses by running `ps -- info`, it's the `Hertz` value. Show us the exact code you're using to read the values and make the calculations.

Comment: yes 'ps --info' is displaying the correct value of Hertz. I am using following code to calculate the CPU time consumption for process in system mode. 'stime' I am reading from file '/proc/<PID>/stat'. 

Code:





clockTicks = sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK);
system_cpu_time = ( stime / clockTicks);

Comment: Please post your actual code, i.e. something that we could run on our machine to try to reproduce your problem.